# Sweetalert is not showing up in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I've visited all the Stackoverflow threads related to SweetAlert's problems in Rails and I still can't make SweetAlert to show up. I can delete records, but they are deleted right away without any confirm message of any kind, and I mean not even with the old alert. If I manually make a `link_to` with a data confirm it's the same story, I can click and go to that URL, but without any confirmation message.

If I remove SweetAlert then the old alert shows up, as expected.

The versions are 2.4.1 and Rails 5.2.2, I'm also using Active Admin gem and I've tested my app with Firefox and Chrome, in both the same happens, and by the way, not even javascripts errors/warnings are shown up in the console.

I have the following gems in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.3'

gem 'sweet-alert-confirm', '~> 0.4.1'

gem 'rails-assets-sweetalert2', '~> 5.1.1', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'

gem 'sweetalert2', '~> 0.0.4'
```

This is my application.js:

```
//= require sweetalert2
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require sweet-alert-confirm
//= require_tree .
```

And this is my application.css:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require sweetalert2
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Comment: Can you please add your JS and erb code showing us what you've configured? Are you requiring sweetalert before jquery on purpose?

Comment: how you wrote link_to code in your view.. please show some code

Comment: @Venom `column("") { |au| link_to "See", admin_admin_user_path(au.id), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } }` and when I click "See" I just go to `admin_admin_user_path(au.id)`, but there's no alert.

Comment: @James.Oliver What do you mean by "configured"? And about the other thing, I've tried `//= require sweetalert2` first, `//= require jquery` first, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: How does sweetalert know it&#39;s supposed to be reacting to that button click? What is the sweetalert/javascript code you&#39;ve written to action the popup? We need to see all of it to get a clear picture. Just adding the gems isn't enough.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require sweetalert2
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require sweet-alert-confirm
//= require_tree.
```

Use like this order in `assets/javascript/applications.js`

Comment: Did that, restarted the server and the problem still persists.